# Number of submatrices from a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, permutations

Let's suppose I have a $4 \times 3$ matrix. Then, is there any way I can compute the number of square submatrices it can form, also the number of square submatrices of given order like say 3, which is 4 ( as I can count it easily for the given matrix), but what about for the number of square submatrices I can form of order 2 from the given matrix. Is it a permutation and combination problem, or we can figure it our intuitively.

Comment: Ordinarily when we ask for a *submatrix* it means a subset of the rows and a subset of the columns from the original matrix, arranged in the same order of appearance.  You might explain what application you have in mind for these submatrices, as it could affect how to count, e.g. permutation or combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an $m \times n$ matrix, and you want to find the number of $p \times q$ submatrices found within it, then you need to choose $p$ rows from the $m$ available, and $q$ columns from the $n$ available.  The total number of such is $\binom{m}{p}\binom{n}{q}$.

For example, if the matrix is $4 \times 3$ and you want to know the number of $3\times 3$ submatrices, the answer is $\binom{4}{3} \binom{3}{3} = 4$.  Or the number of $2\times2$ submatrices will be $\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2} = 6 \times 3 = 18$.